Trying to get SelectList working in BlazorApp form that worked perfectly in RazorApp form
I have a Register form that I had working perfectly in a RazorPages App that I am unable to get working in a similar form in a Blazor Application.  In both applications, I took the basic User Registration form and added a SelectList for Organisations with Id as the Value and Name as the text.
I put both applications in a common solution and got the data for the SelectList from a Persistence layer/project as follows:
In the Razor Pages app, I generated the SelectList as follows:
    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
     ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

     var mhas = await _organisationService.GetMhasList();
     ViewData["SelectListMhas"] = new SelectList(mhas, "Id", "Name");
    }

In the blazor app, data retrieval looked as follows:
public SelectList? SelectListMhas { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var mhas = await OrganisationService.GetMhasList();
    SelectListMhas = new SelectList(mhas, nameof(OrganisationInListDto.Id), nameof(OrganisationInListDto.Name));
}

Both worked perfectly generating the required SelectList
For the Razor Pages app, the required field was coded as follows:
<div class="form-floating mb-3 ">
     <select asp-for="Input.OrganisationId" asp-items="ViewBag.SelectListMhas" class="form-select"></select>
     <label asp-for="Input.OrganisationId"></label>
     <span asp-validation-for="Input.OrganisationId" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>

This worked perfectly and a dropdown list organisations was produced when clicking on the field.
The equivalent code in the blazor app was as follows:
<div class="form-floating mb-3 ">
     <label asp-for="Input.OrganisationId"></label>
     <select asp-for="Input.OrganisationId" asp-items="SelectListMhas" class="form-select"></select>
     <span asp-validation-for="Input.OrganisationId" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>

This did not work.  An empty dropdown list was produced when clicking on the field.
Any help greatly appreciated.
I have also tried using asp-items="@SelectListMhas" but this also did not work.

If you search for Blazor InputSelect you will find many resources on how to implement selects in Blazor - this is an example SO answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64985408/create-an-inputselect-component-that-accepts-lists-with-blazor

Razor tag helpers are not supported in Blazor.

How to accept an answer as correct int Stack Overflow?  When I search for instructions on how to do this, I see the following instructions:  Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.  However this is what I see - no greyed-,out checkmark
